# how to to kill the white flickering splashscreen at the start of phonegap iOS app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, splash-screen, flicker

How to get rid of the white splashscreen flickering at the start of a phonegap iOS application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go in `PhoneGap.plist` and set the `AutoHideSplashScreen` to `NO`

Then whenever you want in your app you can choose to hide the splashscreen with the following code :

```
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I was so happy when I found this, the launch used to be really ugly, now it's running smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default.png and default@2x.png splash screens to something more of your liking.  That gets rid of the white background.

You can find these resources in the *appname/appname*/Resources/Splash folder in an Xcode 4x project.

Comment: Even when setting the splash there's a white flickering too after the splash and right before the app is being displayed on screen. Any ideas for that?

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem with the plugins or some problem with phonegap so

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.splashscreen.show();
}
```

doesn't work for me.

I fixed it by setting the webview alpha to 0 until it's loaded:

3 steps:

1. in the file "CDVViewController.m" in method  "-(void)createGapView" I added:
   self.webView.alpha=0;
2. in the file "MainViewController.m" in method "-(void)WebViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView" I added:     theVebView.alpha=1;
3. in the file "MainController.xib" I changed the background to black (set it to any color you prefer).

Now instead of a white screen flash I have a black one until the content is fully loaded.
good enough for me. (although not perfect)

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

If you have added SplashScreen plugin but `navigator.splashscreen` is still **undefined**, you can try:

```
cordova.exec(null, null, "SplashScreen", "hide", [])
```