# Phonegap showing white screen after the splash screen - IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, cordova

I am trying to kill the whitescreen which automatically loads for two secs after I launch my phonegap application after the splash screen before the login page.

I have tried the `AutoHideSplashScreen to NO` and added `navigator.splashscreen.hide();` in the login.html as referenced in the below reference. But it killed the splash screen instead of white screen. Now on launching the app it takes directly to login.html without a splash screen. Please help me out killing the default white screen between splash screen and login.html.

[how to to kill the white flickering splashscreen at the start of phonegap iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992939/how-to-to-kill-the-white-flickering-splashscreen-at-the-start-of-phonegap-ios-ap)

Answer (score 1):

In your `ViewController's ViewDidload,` Hide the `Webview` and After It will Load Show it in webViewDidFinishLoad method.

First You have to Hide the WebView in View DidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
thewebview.Hidden=YES;
}
```

Then Show the Webview after Loading Finished

```
 -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
        NSLog(@"finish");   
      thewebview.Hidden=NO;
    }
```

Comment: I added it in my Mainview controller still it is not working.


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
      NSLog(@"finish");
      theWebView.Hidden=NO;

Comment: Check My Updated Code :) ( You Have to Hide the Webview First) Also Check Your View BackGround Color (White or Other ? Set as per your Expectation).

Comment: Thanks siba. But my issue is I dont want any bg color to be shown in between the transition from my loader to login.html. 

Secondly is it webView or thewebview variable. Sorry I am newbie to phone gap. Thanks

Comment: in Phonegap the name of Webview is `thewebview` Try my Code and Let me know.

Comment: Semantic Issue:Use of undeclared Variable

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
   thewebview.Hidden=YES;
}

Still Not working :(

Comment: Oh i see. Actually it seems theWebview is Declared in Other Method So Hide it Where its intialized. Or else you Can declare that in .h file and Access anyWhere.