# application showing gray screen for a while after splash screen in winrt

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am working on winRT XAML application, in my main page i have some large images. When i launch the aplication it shows blank screen for a while in between splash screen and main screen. Any solution for this? i think same issue as in [Phonegap showing white screen after the splash screen - IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990396/phonegap-showing-white-screen-after-the-splash-screen-ios) but its in winRT in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something I experienced in the past when I set the page background to an image.  It can take a little while for the image to get loaded and displayed on the page, and therefore you end up with a fraction of a second of unstyled page.  Is that what's going on here?  If so, try reducing the size / quality of your image to see if it makes a difference.  If it does, your work is just starting as you try to find an acceptable compromise between image quality and file size.

Answer (score 0):

Look up "extended splash screen". The technique is basically that you make your app display a splash screen image on a solid color background that looks the same as the one displayed by the Windows shell when it starts your app. The splash screen image is small enough that when your app starts showing just the splash screen - it shows seamlessly and then you can load your first page in the background.